# The intersection of affine subscheme and preimage of affine on separated scheme is affine

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

Let $f:X \to Y$ be a morphism of separated schemes and $V,U$ be affine open subschemes of $X$ and $Y$ respectively. Why is  the intersection $U \cap f^{-1}(V)$ affine? It is easy to prove that intersection of 2 affine schemes on separated scheme is affine, but $f^{-1}(V)$ could be not affine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First things first: since $X$ and $Y$ are separated, the product $X \times Y$ is also separated. I claim the morphism $\langle \mathrm{id}, f \rangle : X \to X \times Y$ is a closed immersion. Indeed, it even has a retraction (namely the projection $X \times Y \to X$), and any morphism into a separated scheme with a retraction is always a closed immersion. (Exercise.)

Now, consider the following diagram:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
U \cap f^{-1} V @>>> X \\
@VVV @VV{\langle \mathrm{id}, f \rangle}V \\
U \times V @>>> X \times Y
\end{CD}$$
It is a pullback diagram, so $U \cap f^{-1} V \to U \times V$ is also a closed immersion. Since $U$ and $V$ are affine, so too are $U \times V$ and $U \cap f^{-1} V$.

We could do all this over an arbitrary base scheme $S$, so long as we remember that "affine $S$-scheme" refers to an $S$-scheme whose structure morphism is affine, *not* an affine scheme with a morphism to $S$.